# Legend and labels for Plotly express line graph

Tags: python, express, plotly, line, legend

I want to draw a three graphs on one x-y axes using Plotly.express.

I've read a CSV file of monthly returns using pandas, and have a pandas dataframe containing four series: Date, IRA, MSCI and SnP.

I converted monthly returns to cumulative returns using a function, so I now have three additional series:IRA_cum, MSCI_cum and SnP_cum.

I want to plot IRA_cum, MSCI_cum and SnP_cum against date and use:

```
fig = px.line(df, x = Date, y = [IRA_cum, MSCI_cum, SnP_cum], 
                markers = True)
fig.show()
```

I get the graph but the Legend says [image].

How do I change the legend to include labels of my choosing.

Thanks!

I was hoping to get a legend with the labels IRA, MSCI and SnP.

Comment: Do you want the column names to be the names you want to display in the legend at the time of data processing? Create three graphs in the `plotly.graph_objects` and set a name for each graph. That name will appear in the legend, so specify it for the name. See  [this](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#line-plot-modes)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the dataframe to `px.line()` so you can refer to column ***names*** for `x` and `y` instead of passing the series themselves (passing
a list of series is equivalent to passing a list of lists, ie. series names if any are discarded).

Assuming these names match the variables in your code, it's a matter of quotes :

```py
fig = px.line(df, x='Date', y=['IRA_cum', 'MSCI_cum', 'SnP_cum'], markers=True)
fig.show()
```